# pandas table with head / tail simultaneously display

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a simple DataFrame :

```
name    value
x1        1.0
x2        2.0
x3        3.0
...
x25       25.0
x26       26.0
x27       27.0
```

I would like to display this df like this :

```
name    top 3   name bottom 3
x25      25.     x1     1. 
x26      26.     x2     2. 
x27      27.     x2     3.
```

I tried :

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x.head(3), x.tail(3)],
                            axis=1)
        )
```

but get an error message :

```
 ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Any ideas ?
any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
pd.concat([df.head(3), df.tail(3)], axis=1)
```

You were nearly there :-)

Comment: what are df1, df2 ? I have only df data frame

Comment: I did : pd.concat([df.head(N).reset_index(), df.tail(N).reset_index()], axis=1) to have the data side by side as I wanted.

Comment: Yes. this will remove the indexes